# `indicator-cpufreq` doesn't seem to work on 14.10

Tags: laptop, performance, cpufreq, 14.10, scaling

I have a Dell XPS 12 and just installed Ubuntu 14.10 (by completely wiping out the old 14.04 installation).

The indicator menu has 2 options, `Performance` and `Powersave`, from which I choose `Performance`.

But even when I have power plugged in and run a compiler as well as a browser, things seem slow and the fan almost never goes off. Indeed, the following is the output from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3667U CPU @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x15
cpu MHz     : 1454.785
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 4988.72
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3667U CPU @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x15
cpu MHz     : 902.832
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 4988.72
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3667U CPU @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x15
cpu MHz     : 1026.562
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 4988.72
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3667U CPU @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x15
cpu MHz     : 1000.878
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 4988.72
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

I used to be able to set the CPU to its max easily with this indicator in Ubuntu 14.04 and 13.10. How do I do this in the new Ubuntu?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You are running by default, the Intel Pstate system in Ubuntu 14.10.  To use the older ACPI method, you need to edit the grub file and reboot:

Open a terminal <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter the folowing lines:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the Nano editor, look for the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`   At the end of the line add `intel_pstate=disable` The whole line shoud now look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"
```

press the keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit Nano.  Then in the terminal, enter the following command to update Grub

`sudo update-grub`

You should now reboot your computer, and find that you are able to set the governors as you did in 14.04

Comment: For anyone else interested, here's the documentation for the intel_pstate driver: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt