# Set CPU governor to performance in 18.04

Tags: cpu, 18.04, governor

I'm trying to set the CPU governor to performance in 18.04, the problem is that it never survives reboots.

I've tried following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/936488/527764) in an answer to this question
[How to set "Performance" instead of "Powersave" as default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929884/how-to-set-performance-instead-of-powersave-as-default) but when I reboot the computer the CPU governor switches back to powersaver.

I've also tried creating a file called `/etc/rc.local` with the line:

```
cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
```

That also doesn't survive reboots.

How can I do this?

Comment: What procedure exactly did you follow? Is the typo in the filename `/etc/rc.local` only in this question, or did you make that same typo when creating it? This question may not be specific to 18.04 and probably shouldn't be a bug report rather than a question here. I think the question could be considered for reopening if you edit it to add more detail.

Comment: The parameter `--governor powersave` should be `--governor performance` ...

Comment: I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/936488/62967) command list, but when I reboot the computer the cpu governor switches back to powersaver. I didn't realise there is a typo in the /etc/rc.local command, I got that from another askubuntu post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956237/run-terminal-sudo-command-at-startup) when I tried to make a script to have the command 'cpupower frequency-set --governor performance' run at startup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently set CPU power management to the powersave governor?](/q/410860/175814)

Comment: Yeah I've tried following that thread, I get this message: j@j-ncase:~$ sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for ondemand

Comment: @DavidFoerster half-way duplicate... See my comment there with an Ubuntu 18.06 specific update: https://askubuntu.com/a/1049270/839002 .

Comment: @Falc: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @Thenightmanager: With your addition the linked question is not a *full* duplicate. ;-]

Comment: @Zanna is correct about reopening after an edit. I believe the question is relevant to all Intel processors that support frequency scaling which probably appeared a decade ago?

Comment: Because of your question I updated my answer in your link first link: https://askubuntu.com/a/936488/307523 to make it work for your question. Thanks.

Comment: Not one reference to cgroups (control groups)... looks like i'll have to answer this. cgroups limits cpu usage, and memory use for users in a group.

Answer (score 49):

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
echo 'GOVERNOR="performance"' | sudo tee /etc/default/cpufrequtils
sudo systemctl disable ondemand
```

Comment: Actually, just the last command is enough.
After `sudo systemctl disable ondemand` and reboot:
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`
shows `performance`.

Comment: is disable ondemand needed or just recommended?

Comment: @JoelBonetR In my case, it was needed. `/etc/default/cpufrequtils` wasn't enough.

Comment: @Yalok Iy I tried what you said first but it didn't work for me but the answer did it.

Comment: @Reza are you also using ubuntu 18.04? Perhaps you are using a newer version and the defaults have changed

Answer (score 11):

## Short Answer

In `/etc/rc.local` put in these commands:

```bash
sleep 120
cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
```

---

### 1 minute after boot automatic switch to Powersave

For whatever reasons my Skylake Intel CPU always starts up in Performance mode and then switches to Powersave mode at the 1 minute mark automatically.

If you set the mode to *Performance* on startup it will be overridden around the 1 minute **Up Time** mark to *Powersave* mode.

In the GIF below, the 3000+ MHz CPU speed at start up appears near the top. The up time appears near the bottom. When up time hits about 1 minute you see CPU MHz drop off. :

[image: CPU goes powersave 1 minute 2.gif]

---

### Program to monitor exact second Powersave invoked

Create this script in `/usr/local/bin/watch-gov.sh`:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# NAME: watch-gov.sh
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Set governnor to performance and watch for change
#       Ask Ubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04/1084727#1084727
# CALL: called from `/etc/rc.local`
# DATE: Created Oct 18, 2018.

echo performance | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
last_gov=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor)
Uptime=$(uptime)
echo "watch-gov.sh: Set to performance at $Uptime " > /tmp/watch-gov.log

for ((i=0; i<300; i++)) ; do
    curr_gov=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor)
    if [ $last_gov != $curr_gov ] ; then
        last_gov=$curr_gov
        Uptime=$(uptime)
        echo "watch-gov.sh: Current governor: $last_gov Uptime: $Uptime" >> \
            /tmp/watch-gov.log
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Call the script in `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0` command (explained in detail below).

One minute after logging in look at the output:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/watch-gov.log
watch-gov.sh: Set to performance at  17:50:09 up 0 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 
watch-gov.sh: Current governor: powersave Uptime:  17:51:09 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.89, 0.62, 0.22
```

Confirmation from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/614390/307523) states this 1 minute force to `powersave` governor is controlled by `/etc/init.d/ondemand`.

---

### Sleep 120 seconds before setting Performance Mode

The simplest way to stay in Performance mode is to edit `/etc/rc.local` and insert these lines before the last line containing `exit 0`:

```bash
sleep 120 # Give CPU startup routines time to settle.
echo performance | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Save the file and reboot.

If you insert the new lines after `exit 0` it will never be executed.

To setup `/etc/rc.local` in 18.04 see: [How to Enable `/etc/rc.local` with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)

---

### Caveats

Your machine will probably run 10 to 15 degrees C hotter.

You may need to remove other programs that change CPU frequency if they override your Performance settings in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Which package has `cpupower` and which GUI you have that animgif from? I'm trying to tune a Ryzen 7 with `cpufreq-utils` but it feels sluggish even with the performance governor

Comment: @CsabaToth I use **Conky** to display CPU, RAM, HDD, SDD, Network and other system details. You don't need **cpupower** but it is part of `cpufrequtils` package. If system is sluggish try **Unity** desktop instead of default **Gnome** desktop.

Comment: @WinEunuchs2Unix thanks, I haven't ever heard of Conky, and it was installed onto my system. I'm running Devuan BTW with Xfce4. So Conky says my CPU frequency is 550 MHz (0.55 GHz), which explains the sluggishness and is what I expected, but `cpufreq-info` tells 3.2 GHz and I'm forcing `performance` governor. I need to open a Question for this.

Comment: /etc/rc.local & /etc/init.d/ondemand don't exist in 18.04..

Comment: @doug To setup `/etc.rc.local` in 18.04 see: [How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)

Comment: This is a simple way to do it, thanks. I had to modify your sleep line to fork it in a separate process, as running rc.local was blocking startup. Just changed it to "$(sleep 60; cpupower frequency-set --governor performance) &". Boot runs at full speed, and then it ramps down for lower power steady state operation in an octoprint server.

Answer (score 8):

Default Ubuntu kernel configurations are such that the performance CPU frequency scaling governor will be used during boot. The relevant section of the kernel configuration file ( `/boot/config-4.15.0-36-generic` , in this example) is:

```
#
# CPU Frequency scaling
#
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ATTR_SET=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_COMMON=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_STAT=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_POWERSAVE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_USERSPACE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_ONDEMAND is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_CONSERVATIVE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_SCHEDUTIL is not set
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_POWERSAVE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_USERSPACE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_CONSERVATIVE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_SCHEDUTIL=y

#
# CPU frequency scaling drivers
#
CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE=y
CONFIG_X86_PCC_CPUFREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ_CPB=y
CONFIG_X86_POWERNOW_K8=y
CONFIG_X86_AMD_FREQ_SENSITIVITY=m
CONFIG_X86_SPEEDSTEP_CENTRINO=y
CONFIG_X86_P4_CLOCKMOD=m
```

But also by default during boot up the `ondemand` service is executed. It sleeps for 1 minutes and then changes the scaling governor to either `interactive`, `ondemand` or `powersave`, depending on availability. In turn availability depends on which CPU frequency scaling driver you are using. The code is (in multiple locations, search for `ondemand`):

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ondemand
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"
### END INIT INFO

# Don't run if we're going to start an Android LXC container:
[ ! -f /etc/init/lxc-android-config.conf ] || exit 0

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

AVAILABLE="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors"
DOWN_FACTOR="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand/sampling_down_factor"

case "$1" in
    start)
        start-stop-daemon --start --background --exec /etc/init.d/ondemand -- background
        ;;
    background)
        sleep 60 # probably enough time for desktop login

        [ -f $AVAILABLE ] || exit 0
        read governors < $AVAILABLE
        case $governors in
                *interactive*)
                        GOVERNOR="interactive"
                        break
                        ;;
                *ondemand*)
                        GOVERNOR="ondemand"
                        case $(uname -m) in
                                ppc64*)
                                        SAMPLING=100
                                ;;
                        esac
                        break
                        ;;
                *powersave*)
                        GOVERNOR="powersave"
                        break
                        ;;
                *)
                        exit 0
                        ;;
        esac

        for CPUFREQ in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
        do
                [ -f $CPUFREQ ] || continue
                echo -n $GOVERNOR > $CPUFREQ
        done
        if [ -n "$SAMPLING" ] && [ -f $DOWN_FACTOR ]; then
                echo -n $SAMPLING > $DOWN_FACTOR
        fi
        ;;
    restart|reload|force-reload)
        echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
    stop)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Why is it called "ondemand", but it sets other governors (for example with the intel_pstate driver it will set the powersave governor)? Because this tool pre-dates the intel_pstate driver, back to a time when, by far, the dominant frequency scaling driver was the acpi-cpufreq driver, and "ondemand" was the preferred Ubuntu default governor.

So, one way to boot and stay using the performance CPU frequency scaling governor is to disable the service that changes away from it (which was also mentioned in another answer):

Before:

```
~$ systemctl list-units --all --type=service | grep ondemand
  ondemand.service                                      loaded    inactive dead    Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor
~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
ondemand
ondemand
```

Disable the service:

```
~$ sudo systemctl disable ondemand
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ondemand.service.
```

re-boot, then check again (being sure to wait a minute after the re-boot):

```
doug@s17:~$ systemctl list-units --all --type=service | grep ondemand
doug@s17:~$
doug@s17:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
performance
```

Note: the examples in this answer are from a computer that uses the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver. If you are using the intel_pstate driver, with no ondemand governor, the powersave governor will be used by default.

Anticipated question: Why do my CPU frequencies scale, even when using the performance governor?

Answer: Modern processors scale the CPU frequency, even in performance mode and as a function of the depth of the idle state they go into. If you really want to lock the CPU frequency then disable all idle states deeper than 0. However, note that it will cost a huge huge amount of power.

Personally, and as mentioned in another answer, I use the performance governor or the powersave governor as a function of whatever work I am doing. My scripts are a little different:

```
$ cat set_cpu_performance
#! /bin/bash
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "performance" > $file; done

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

and:

```
$ cat set_cpu_powersave
#! /bin/bash
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

example usage (on a computer using the intel_pstate driver):

```
$ sudo ./set_cpu_performance
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

Comment: There are so many exotic and complicated solutions out there, but `systemctl disable ondemand` is by far the simplest option that I've seen anywhere, and it works great. I also had to do `echo 'GOVERNOR="performance"' > /etc/default/cpufrequtils` to persist between reboots, as [mentioned above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049313/266).

Comment: Thanks for this great summary. On my machine (Pop_OS 21.04), Kernel 5.13, the `ondemand` service does not appear to exist? `sudo systemctl status ondemand` says: 
`Unit ondemand.service could not be found.`

Comment: @Matthias : Yes, as far as I know the ondemand service is an Ubuntu thing.

Comment: @DougSmythies I researched it a bit, and it turns out that I was using the `intel_pstate` scaling driver. It only supports two governors: performance and powersave. I don't think it's Ubuntu related but rather based on the scaling driver. When I switch to `intel_cpufreq`, I see more, including `ondemand`. This is a pretty good summary: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/cpufreq.html

Comment: You are confusing the ondemand governor with the Ubuntu on demand service. The two are not related at all. The ubuntu service sets the governor after boot. It used to wait one minute, but does't anymore. The service is Named "ondemand" because way back that was all it did, was set the governor to "ondemand", as at the time the intel_pstate driver did not exist. @Matthias .

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense -- thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4):

You'll first need to install cpufrequtils;

```
sudo apt install cpufrequtils
```

then, perform a restart and set cpufrequency to performance,

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g performance
```

Note: If you ran the above command without restarting, then you'd have to edit edit the file in `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils` and change the line that says

```
GOVERNOR=ondemand
```

to

```
GOVERNOR=performance
```

then run;

```
sudo sh /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils start
```

it'd probably prompt you to restart your systemctl daemon, so do it like this;

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

this should do the work. then view your cpufrequency with;

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i mhz
```

Answer (score 2):

What I did was use the file /etc/rc.local

To help you find your paths, use:

```
find / -name scaling_governor
find / -name scaling_max_freq
```

This works for my setup, but you just need to edit it for your setup

I added to /etc/rc.local using nano:

```
# Set CPU Governor and Freq at boot up
 echo "performance" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
 echo 1500000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
 echo 2000000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
 echo "performance" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

directly under the shebang line.
Close nano with Ctrl-X and Y to save

Then for 18.04 (may not work on 16.04) on the command line run:

```
systemctl disable ondemand
```

Then on the command line - read /etc/rc.local and then reboot:

```
/etc/rc.local
reboot
```

if /etc/rc.local chokes and errors then make sure it's chmod +x /etc/rc.local

Comment: One other thing that I do is to edit /etc/init.d/ondemand or ondemand needs to be moved to ondemandzzz to disable it. 
There is a sleep 60 in /etc/init.d/ondemand before it sets the governor. Even though rc.local will change it to performance at boot time, 60 seconds later it gets changed by /etc/init.d/ondemand.
In /etc/init.d/ondemand change the line: echo -n $GOVERNOR > $CPUFREQ  to: echo -n "performance" > $CPUFREQ if you decide to keep /etc/init.d/ondemand working...

Answer (score 2):

I am using this bash script to set the `performance` governor:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 0 --governor performance
sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 1 --governor performance
sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 2 --governor performance
sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 3 --governor performance
sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 4 --governor performance
sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 5 --governor performance
sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 6 --governor performance
sudo cpufreq-set --cpu 7 --governor performance

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Make is executable `chmod +x cpu.sh` and run at any time You need (ever right after every computer start/reboot).

Comment: instead of modifying each cpu core separately you can specifiy the `-r` option "modify all hardware-related CPUs at the same time"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
In my case I wanted to set the governor to 'schedutil', but after a reboot I would always find the governor to be 'ondemand'.
I read and did try most solutions presented here to no avail.

What did the trick for me, and I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2 was finding the file:

/lib/systemd/set-cpufreq

editing it to insert the lines:

```
    *schedutil*)
            GOVERNOR="schedutil"
            break
            ;;
```

so now the file reads:

```
    #! /bin/sh
    # Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"/"powersave"      where available
    set -eu

    FIRSTCPU=`cut -f1 -d- /sys/devices/system/cpu/online`
    AVAILABLE="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$FIRSTCPU/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors"
    DOWN_FACTOR="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand/sampling_down_factor"

    [ -f $AVAILABLE ] || exit 0

    read governors < $AVAILABLE
    case $governors in
            *interactive*)
                   GOVERNOR="interactive"
                   break
                   ;;
            *schedutil*)
                   GOVERNOR="schedutil"
                   break
                   ;;
            *ondemand*)
                   GOVERNOR="ondemand"
                   case $(uname -m) in
                           ppc64*)
                           SAMPLING=100
                   ;;
                   esac
                   break
                   ;;
            *powersave*)
                   GOVERNOR="powersave"
                   break
                   ;;
            *)
                   exit 0
                   ;;
    esac

    [ -n "${GOVERNOR:-}" ] || exit 0

    echo "Setting $GOVERNOR scheduler for all CPUs"

    for CPUFREQ in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
    do
            [ -f $CPUFREQ ] || continue
            echo -n $GOVERNOR > $CPUFREQ
    done
    if [ -n "${SAMPLING:-}" ] && [ -f $DOWN_FACTOR ]; then
            echo -n $SAMPLING > $DOWN_FACTOR
    fi.
```

and now when I boot my computer it starts with the 'schedutil' governor!

Answer (score 0):

A simple script to switch between powersave and performance mode. You can try with any of the 'wrmsr' commenting out one in below script. I don't know why, but writing 0 to register worked well for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

# argument: powersave or performance
if [ $# != 1 ]
then
  echo "You should specify CPU driver governor as argument!"
  exit 1
fi

totalCPUs=$(lscpu | grep '^CPU(s):' | awk '{print $2}')

for (( cpuIndex=0; cpuIndex<$totalCPUs; cpuIndex++ ))
do
   echo "Optimizing CPU $cpuIndex"
   cpufreq-set -c $cpuIndex -g $1
done

if [ $1 == "performance" ]
then
  modprobe msr
  controlRegVal=$(rdmsr 0x1FC)
  #wrmsr 0x1FC $controlRegVal
  wrmsr 0x1FC 0
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, after setting GOVERNOR="performance" and disabling ondemand, I also had to restart cpufrequtils service to actually make it work:

```
sudo systemctl restart cpufrequtils.service
```