# How downgrade gnome-shell in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

A question stemming from question [Ubuntu 18.04 slow gnome after 2019 update: virus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138691): Is it possible to downgrade gnome-shell?  I am advised to downgrade in Ubuntu 18.04 from gnome-shell version 3.28.3 (April 25 2019) to 3.28.1.  Is there a safe recipe for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version string for gnome-shell 3.28.1 is 3.28.1-0ubuntu2 which is still available in repository/pool. To downgrade run,

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-common=3.28.1-0ubuntu2 gnome-shell=3.28.1-0ubuntu2
```

These won't be automatically upgraded unless done explicitly.

Comment: Will that fly w/o deleting the installed one?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yeah, just tested on a virtual machine that is fully updated. [Output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Kc8MpqJtCB/) with warnings of being downgraded for your reference.

Comment: @Kulfy: thanks!  But the downgrade did not repair my slowness-after-update problem.  How do I go back to 3.28.3 and automatic upgrade?

Comment: @RobRutten You download deb from Ubuntu packages and install that using dpkg

Comment: more interestingly, how do I get all possible downgradable version numbers?

Comment: @Polv `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-common gnome-shell` would show available versions from currently configured repositories/PPA.

Answer (score 0):

One should be careful that no packages are removed.  The answer posted by Kulfy does not include `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`, so it ends up removing that as well as `gnome-tweaks`. The proper command in Ubuntu 20.04 is:

```bsh
sudo apt install gnome-shell=3.36.1-5ubuntu1 gnome-shell-common=3.36.1-5ubuntu1 gnome-shell-extension-prefs=3.36.1-5ubuntu1
```