# How to delete CPU-stats from cpufreq?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, cpu, 32-bit, cpufreq

Is there a way to delete the old stats for a fresh start? I have set max CPU-speed to 950 MHz in file `cpufrequtils`. My issue is  that this limitation is not in action when booting up, during which `cpufrequtils` is collecting data  as can be seen from output: `cpufreq stats: 1.20 GHz:27,27%`. So after boot i would like to reset the stats to zero.

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.20 GHz, 1.07 GHz, 933 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 950 MHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 933 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.20 GHz:27,27%, 1.07 GHz:0,48%, 933 MHz:47,91%, 800   MHz:24,34%  (1449)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 1.20 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.20 GHz, 1.07 GHz, 933 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace,  powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 950 MHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 933 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 1.20 GHz:30,29%, 1.07 GHz:0,29%, 933 MHz:51,91%, 800  MHz:17,52%  (763)
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Edit: Trying to follow advice given in answer, but there is no reset in folder:

```
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats$ ls -l
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 apr 28 09:46 time_in_state
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 apr 28 09:46 total_trans
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 apr 28 09:46 trans_table
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats$ dir
time_in_state  total_trans  trans_table
peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats$
```

Answer (score 3):

From: [CPU frequency and voltage scaling statistics in the Linux(TM) kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/cpufreq-stats.txt)

```
<mysystem>:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats # ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May 14 16:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 May 14 15:58 ..
--w-------  1 root root 4096 May 14 16:06 reset
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 May 14 16:06 time_in_state
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 May 14 16:06 total_trans
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 May 14 16:06 trans_table
```

### reset

Write-only attribute that can be used to reset the stat counters. This can be
useful for evaluating system behaviour under different governors without the
need for a reboot.

This should reset all the stats:

```
echo '1' | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/stats/reset
```

---

From: [How to use cpufrequtils](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils#cpufreq-set)

#### cpufreq-set

Allows setting

```
-d  minimum frequency,
-u  maximum frequency,
-f  specific frequency (userspace governor must be set first) and
-g  governor on a
-c  specific CPU.
```

`cpufreq-set` needs root privileges in order to work.

Look for this in your setup:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -u 950MGhz
```

and remove it. Or add this to your setup:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -u 1.20Ghz
```

---

From: [HowTo CpuFrequencyScaling](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling#Configuration)

GOVERNOR variable from /etc/default/cpufrequtils not taking effect

So, you configured the GOVERNOR variable in /etc/default/cpufrequtils and after reboot you notice by running cpufreq-info that the active governor is still "ondemand".

This may happen if you have laptop-mode-tools installed. laptop-mode configures the active governor via the following variables: BATT_CPU_GOVERNOR, LM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR, NOLM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR. You can override them to your liking in /etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf:

```
BATT_CPU_GOVERNOR=powersave
LM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR=conservative
NOLM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR=ondemand
```

---

From: [Arch Linux CPU frequency scaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#Setting_maximum_and_minimum_frequencies)

#### Setting maximum and minimum frequencies

In rare cases, it may be necessary to manually set maximum and minimum frequencies.

To set the maximum clock frequency (clock_freq is a clock frequency with units: GHz, MHz):

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -u clock_freq
```

To set the minimum clock frequency:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -d clock_freq
```

To set the CPU to run at a specified frequency:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -f clock_freq
```

Comment: Thanks. Directly after booting up, the percentage for 1.20 GHz is the highest. Then, for each cpufreq-info, it is sinking.  That's why I would like to get rid of stats invoving data from startup, so I can better see how the max of 950 MHz works . Changed to userspace, but no obvious difference.

Comment: @PeterEriksson Almost all Ubuntu based laptops start at maximum frequency during the first minute and then speed governors are engaged. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04/1084727#1084727

Comment: Seems like cpufreq collects stats during boot, and that the set max CPU-speed is not yet activated.

Comment: The max is deliberatly set to 950 MHz. Fan not working.

Comment: @PeterEriksson I misunderstood the question at first. Check the first part of the answer now. Additionally a new fan can be as little as $20.

Comment: See my edit in the question. So how can I get a reset-file? Actually, I really enjoy the silence that came with the no fan situation!

Comment: @PeterEriksson Try: `echo '1' | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/stats/reset`

Comment: Problem seems to be that there is no file "reset" in the directory "stats". This is what happens:   `peter@peter-HP-Compaq-2510p:~$ echo '1' | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/stats/reset    
tee: '/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/stats/reset': No such file or directory
1`

Comment: @PeterEriksson does the directory exist? `ll /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/`

Comment: Yes, and output from `ls -l`is edited into the question. Obviously, the reset-file isn't included in the installation of cpufreq.

Comment: @PeterEriksson I'll review the documentation again.

Comment: After having removed and reinstalled cpufrequtils, there is still, even after reboot, no reset file in the stats directory. I'm on 32-bit 18.04.2 Xubuntu system.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and do not even have a `.../stats` sub-directory at all. I've spent hours on this issue and will have to tap out...

Comment: Tried installing cpufrequtils on my other hp 2510p which runs on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS. This installation came with a reset file in stats and when executing `echo '1' | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/stats/reset` stats went to zero. So this issue must be about different distributions of cpufrequtils?

Comment: @PeterEriksson Yes the 32-bit versions have pretty much been abandoned. The on-line documentation I found was probably based on up-to-date modern 64-bit distributions. Good to know I wasn't going crazy trying to solve this problem :). Thanks for the update!