# AMD vs Intel for CPU throttling

Tags: cpu, amd-processor

I currently run Ubuntu on my pc that has an AMD Ryzen 5 2400g. I tried to disable the CPU throttling and it seemed to have worked but I am not too sure if it has. (increased from 1600 to 2400 where my max cpu is 3600)

The method I used was from here:
[Set CPU governor to performance in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04)

I was wondering if someone could tell me whether the difference in core matters in how much I can disable CPU throttling. How I should go about disabling it more effectively for my computer specs?

Comment: What CPU scaling driver and governor are you using now? Do `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and edit the output into your question. I assume you have set the performance governor, just checking. Keep in mind that even with the performance governor CPU can throttle themselves as a function of deep idle states.

Comment: yes it printed out a bunch of the word "performance" so I believe that has been set.

Comment: which CPU scaling driver?

Comment: acpi-cpufreq is the one

Answer (score 0):

Using the acpi-cpufreq CPU scaling driver with the performance governor, as you are, should provide the fastest CPU frequency ramp up possible under load. Note that modern processors can still scale down CPU frequency as a function of deep idle states, even with the performance governor. To demonstrate what your processor will actually ramp up to, put a full 100% load on one CPU. For example:

```
$ taskset -c 2 yes > /dev/null
```