# not able to change cpu governer

Tags: performance, cpu, 21.10

i'm currently using ubuntu 21.10 and i'm relatively new to linux so i'm not exactly sure how to change stuff but here's what i did seeking answers on diffrent forums

```
cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4.0 us
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.20 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.20 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.20 GHz.
                  The governor "schedutil" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 1.90 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
```

i want to change it to performance since the OS is jittering while using it since it is not utilizing 100% of CPU power i tired doing this but got an error

```
sudo systemctl disable schedutil
Failed to disable unit: Unit file schedutil.service does not exist.
```

I'm not sure how to set performance governer permanently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set CPU governor to performance in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04)

Comment: ah did't happen to check that! sorry. i did that and it changed will it remain permanent? because i sudo update-rc.d schedutil disable
[sudo] password for a: 
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for schedutil

Comment: I believe so, yes - unless something was drastically changed from 18.04 to 21.10, which I don't think is the case.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: There is no such service as `schedutil`. The service was `ondemand`, not to be confused with the CPU frequency scaling governor of the same name. What has changed recently is the Ubuntu kernel configuration default CPU frequency scaling governor, which has gone from `PERFORMANCE` to `SCHEDUTIL`, thus obsoleting all answers/comments that relied on the default governor being `PERFORMANCE`, many of which I wrote. I would now suggest specifying the desired governor on the kernel command line in grub.