# indicator-cpufreq always shows only one bar on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, indicator, cpufreq, intel-cpu

On Ubuntu 14.10 the `indicator-cpufreq` always shows only one bar. I can switch between *Performance* and *Powersave* but the indicator icon never changes. It always shows only the one most bottom bar. I have switched to *Performance*, but even when compiling large projects, the indicator does not change.

What does this mean? Is my CPU running on low speed all the time? Or is it a bug with the indicator?

`lshw` shows: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz`

Answer (score 3):

You are running by default, the Intel Pstate system in Ubuntu 14.10.  To use the older ACPI method, you need to edit the grub file and reboot:

Open a terminal <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter the folowing lines:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the Nano editor, look for the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`   At the end of the line add `intel_pstate=disable` The whole line shoud now look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"
```

press the keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit Nano.  Then in the terminal, enter the following command to update Grub

`sudo update-grub`

You should now reboot your computer, and find that you are able to set the governors as you did in 14.04

This answer has been taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541143/indicator-cpufreq-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-14-10/541412#541412).

---

Additionally, the indicator will crash upon startup if the BIOS setting for "SpeedStep" is disabled. To fix this, go into your BIOS settings and enable "SpeedStep".

Comment: After adding intel_pstate=disable the indicator crashes after login :-(

Comment: @Witek You probably need to enable SpeedStep in your BIOS settings to prevent crashing.