# Xubuntu 14.10 - after upgrade from 14.04 CPU Scaling not working

Tags: xubuntu, 14.10, thinkpad, cpu, scaling

I upgraded my system from 14.04 to 14.10 and after that `indicator-cpufreq` was showing only two options: powersave and performance. After following [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/541412/353763)
I was able to see all my CPU frequencies, but the CPU is always on 1500 MHz, although i have i3 from 779/800 MHz up to 1900 MHz. 
It's a Thinkpad S440. With 14.04 CPU Scaling was working fine.

P.S. If i restart computer i have normal frequencies (lowest at 779 MHz) as long as it is plugged on AC, but after first standby or as soon as i pull cable off and the laptop is on battery i get these high CPU frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be `cpufreqd` (daemon) which was installed after update. I removed it and installed `acpi` (although the `acpid` was still there).

Removing `cpufreqd` seems to have solved my problem.